# Android VideoView Black bar appearing at bottom

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a videoview to play a video and after that some other buttons in that layout.But the black bar of the video is appearing on bottom of layout.What i should do to make the blackbar on videoview's bottom.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/White" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_intro"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@color/intro2_bg"
        android:padding="@dimen/sidearea_padding" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/remove_page_from_introthird"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cross" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footer_btns_layout_linear"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" >

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/videoView_introthree"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer_btns_layout_linear"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/prev_btn2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/previous_selecter" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nxt_btn2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/get_start_selecter" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mSDCardbutton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/play_sdcard" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mServerbutton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/play_server" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mRawbutton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/play_raw" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mbutton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button" />

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/VideoView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In this layout, buttons are at top.You can keep it at bottom.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried the videoview in outer layout and buttons in inner layout.But it is not working.

Comment: I mean the black bar that is appearing on video hover is on the top of bottom buttons